# How to solve glitch in GTA Online Prison Break set up

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

The third set up in the prison break heist is where one team steals a police schedule and the other steals a vehicle. I've been on the police team every attempt so far. Every time I get the schedule, burn the car, etc. you have to bring the schedule back to the leaders heist room. So I've done that then the other team dies. But for once the other team didn't die. But this time when you burn the car it didn't show a yellow waypoint back to the planning room. It said however to take the schedule to the planning room. So we drove there without the waypoint but when I got into the circle it wouldn't let me go into my apartment when the mission objective was active. This has happened twice now. How do I stop this?

Comment: Iirc you have to wait for the other team to get there, so you can all go in together.

Comment: @Chippies I didn't need to wait when I had done it before

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no real way to fix this unless one of you leave the heist. It has happened to me too on a couple of occasions and each time we grew tired of waiting and had to leave the heist.